# Relation does not Exist/ Programming Error in django

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

My this django WebApp works fine in Local development but when I tried it in production it says relation does not exist, I am probably sure it would be the problem with data base connection in production, it is sqlite3 on local but in production on heroku it is postgresql and I am unable to make it functional properly even I modified database connectivity in settings.py from sqlite3 to postgresql by applying new provided database credentials

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pojea.png)

Comment: Either that relation doesn't exist or the user 'dfblranarg7fjd' doesn't have access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run a migration after connecting the new database?
Looks like the table it looking for does not exists.

Comment: I actually tried a lot but could not find any such functionality in heroku!
 if u know plz lemme know

Comment: You have to create a new superuser in every new DB.
So create a new :)